# Perl argument that contains newline character

Tags: perl, shell, arguments

I am trying to write a perl script that emails whatever I give it in the first argument, but I need the email body to have multiple lines. When I pass text to the script (Using MIME::Lite, fyi), the email body only has a single line because the "\n" I pass in the script do not seem to be converted to newline in the email body.

Here is an example

Script Brief Content:

```
    my $message = $ARGV[0];
    #blah blah
    sendEmail $message;
```

Command Example when calling script

```
sendEmail.pl "Issue: CPU usage is high \n Time: 11:20AM \n"
```

What I need:

```
Issue: CPU issue
Time: 12:00AM
```

What I get:

```
Issue: CPU issue \n Time: 12:00AM \n
```

Even if I just want to print to output that string as in `print "$message"`, I get the same output.

How can I force perl to consider \n characters that are passed to it so that it moves content to next line when it sees that character?

Comment: It's actually a _new line_. A _carriage return_ is a `\r`. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't look like an issue with `perl`, it's a problem with the `bash` command that you typed. When you enter the following string literal in `bash`:

```
"Issue: CPU usage is high \n Time: 11:20AM \n"
```

`bash` does not interpret the `\n` character sequences as line breaks. You need a different syntax for that. You can use either of the following:

```
# bash
sendEmail.pl $'Issue: CPU usage is high\nTime: 11:20AM\n'
```

or

```
# bash or sh
sendEmail.pl 'Issue: CPU usage is high
Time: 11:20AM
'
```

Comment: I'd call it "a problem with how you're using bash", not "a problem with bash". Bash is behaving precisely as specified and documented.